# Python RPG Confusion

Tags: python

I am having a problem with my code where, when called, it seems to make the fight go on longer than it should.

I think the problem lies in the if statements, so I have been playing around with them , but I can't seem to get it right.

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, Name, HP, ATK, DEF, Damage):
        self.Name = Name
        self.HP = HP
        self.ATK = ATK
        self.DEF = DEF
        self.Damage = Damage

def attack(attacker, attackee):  # The attack function
    hit = random.randint(min_roll, max_roll) + attacker.ATK

    if (hit > attackee.DEF):
        print(attacker.Name, "inflicts", attacker.Damage)

        attackee.HP = attackee.HP - attacker.Damage

        if attackee.HP <= 0:  # if the attackee's health drops below zero
            print("With a forceful attack,", attackee.Name, "dies.")
        else:
            print(attackee.Name, "has", attackee.HP, "HP remaining.")
    else:
        print("You missed. Better defend!")


def fight(attacker, enemy):  # The attack loop takes in two enemy objects
    while(attacker.HP >= 0 and enemy.HP >=0):
        if attacker.HP >= 0 and enemy.HP >= 0:
            attack(attacker, enemy)
        else:
            print("You're dead")

        if enemy.HP >= 0 and attacker.HP >= 0:
            attack(enemy, attacker)
        else:
            print("The enemy is dead")

theClass= Enemy("warrior", 10, 4, 5, 5)
skeleton1 = Enemy("The Skeleton", 10, 4, 5, 5)  # This creates a new Skeleton enemy. The order is the Name, HP, ATK, DEF, and Damage.

fight(theClass, skeleton1)
```

The output should stop exactly when one of the characters die, and each character should attack only once per volly. For some reason when i ran the code this time, the final attack had the warrior run three times before the skeleton died.

I have also seen that sometimes it also works fine. The inconsistent results are not okay. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want them to keep attacking when they are at 0 hp? What's the output when you change the checks to be `if enemy.HP > 0 and attacker.HP > 0`?

Additionally, it may be helpful to put a `return` statement in the clause where you find out one of them is dead; that way, you can be sure that the fight ends once one of them has died.

Comment: Using a variable from the attack function cleaned it up and made is much more strraight forward. After making the appropriate modification, it worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In the `attack` function you say:

> `if attackee.HP <= 0:`  # if the attackee's health drops below zero

From the comment, and the `if` statements in `fight`, it seems that when the health is exactly 0, you do not consider them dead and they can still fight.
But that `if` statement will print the death message also if health is equal to 0. Just edit it to be consistent:

```
if attackee.HP < 0:
```

and it will works.

If instead you want them to die when the health is exactly 0, keep the equality in the `attack` function but remove it from all the `if` statements in the `fight` function.